# Scala on Linux/MIPS and Linux/PowerPC

Tags: scala, mips, powerpc

It's now quite common for embedded systems to run Linux on MIPS or PowerPC processors.

How well do Scala programs run on such systems ?

Obviously Scala requires a JVM - are good JVMs available on MIPS and PowerPC ?
In particular are there JVMs that support JIT or AOT compilation ?

Are there any requirements beyond a JVM, the standard JRE library, and the Scala library ?

Thanks in advance,

Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/) has full support for [the Java Virtual Machine Specification Java SE 8 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) on both Linux/MIPS and Linux/PowerPC. It is purely a JVM, in order for it to be actually useful, you need to pair it with a JRE. JamVM supports both [GNU Classpath](http://gnu.org/software/classpath/) as well as the OpenJDK 6, 7, and 8 class libraries. It can also be used as a JVM inside [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/). It has an inline-threaded interpreter with stack caching that can give performance comparable to a simple JIT compiler, but it cannot compete with sophisticated high-performance JIT compilers such as HotSpot C2, Oracle JRockit, or IBM J9.

Chinese MIPS CPU vendor [open-sourced an OpenJDK 8 port to MIPS](http://hg.loongnix.org/jdk8-mips64-public/) two weeks ago.

[The IBM J9 JDK](https://ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/) naturally has support for Linux/PowerPC. Or actually rather for Linux/POWER.

A company named [MicroDoc](https://microdoc.com/) sells a [MIPS port of Oracle Java SE Embedded 8](https://microdoc.com/java-se-embedded-8-mips-linux/) and a [PowerPC port](http://microdoc.com/java-se-embedded-8-powerpc-linux/). I don't believe Scala runs on Java SE Embedded, though.